# SQl - Copy tables from a linked server to a table on SQL 2008 R2

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to copy all tables from a linked server to a table on SQL 2008 R2. I have tried the following but it gives an error. The database that I need the tables copied to is called Apples. My linked server is called 'MYSQL' and database on the linked server is called 'drupaltest':

```
select * into Apples
from OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'SELECT * FROM MYSQL.drupaltest')
```

This is the error:
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" returned message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.28-log]Table 'mysql.drupaltest' doesn't exist".
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You say that the database is named `drupaltest`, and the error is referring to a table.

Assuming that `MYSQL` is just your linked server name, try to specify the table...

```
... from OPENQUERY(MYSQL, 'SELECT * FROM drupaltest.table')
```

Comment: I need all of the tables copied over. I have it copting for one table at a time. I have multiple tables. I wanted to try to copy them all at the same time. Thank you.

Comment: Do these multiple tables all have the same amount of columns?

Comment: No, that is different. I tried to use the Import/Export Wizard but my linked server does not display in the  wizard.

Comment: From what you posted above, it seems you need to run `OPENQUERY` for each table.

Comment: Is there a way to copy them all instead of one by one?

Comment: @user1863593 Perhaps [this article](http://drupal.org/node/1005252#comment-3952558) may help.